# Not able to bind events in Backbone view - when using modal

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have the following div which contains a list of modals

```
<div id="listofModals>
    <div id="fooModal>
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="next"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I create a view on fooModal - its not able to bind any event on the button inside .

Where `$el="#listofModals"`

```
events: {'click .next': 'callSomefunction'},
```

Whats wrong here ?

Here is the View Declaration :

```
return xxxxx.View.extend({
        __name__: 'myView',        
        events: {'click .next': 'next'},        
        template: Handlebars.compile(MyTemplate),
        initialize: function (options) {            
        }
        next:function(){
           console.log('Here);
        }
});
```

When i Print this.$el -without initializing it

```
    [div#listOfModals, context: document, 
selector: "#listOfModals", 
jquery: "1.9.1", 
constructor: function, 
init: function…]0: 
div#listOfModalscontext: documentlength: 1selector: "#listOfModals"__proto__: jQuery[0]
```

Comment: Could you post all declaration of view?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan find the declartation above..Also when i print the $el - it gives selector as "#listofModals"

Comment: Also - can you please explain the vote for close

Comment: `this.$el` should be jquery element and not the string selector. In view code you need to prevent the default behavior of anchor element. How do you appending this view to the DOM?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan Please check what this.$el prints

Comment: Is seems like it is a jQuery element. You didn't answer my question. How do you appending this view to the DOM?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan  thisView.$el.html(thisView.template(thisView.displayData));

Comment: your are appending template to the this.$el outside of the view?